# State representation : I have less order of canonical form than state variables

Tags: control-theory

When I describe a simple system with spring-damper feedback with 4 states variables, I obtain a transfer function or canonical form of this transfer function with 3 poles and a reduced form with order 3.
Why ? some state variables can be contracted ?
You can see code from from maxima

[first part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3PQD.png)
[image]

[second part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtWJH.png)
[image]

Comment: Can you type the equations instead of the screenshots?

Comment: What are the parameters for `tf:trasnfer_function`?

Comment: The input is I and the output is speed1. The transfer function is correct but the problem is that the canonical form give a matrix smaller than the number of state variables.

Answer (score 1):

Your question and approach is unclear but from what I understand, you had a fourth order transfer function and when you transformed it into canonical form, you got a third order system. If this is indeed the case, it is not unusual. You are probably obtaining a minimum realization of the system (happens with pole-zero cancellations).